# CSS div/overflow: Why does the first HTML file work but not the second?

Tags: html, css, html-table, width, overflow

Notice how the first HTML/CSS works when you re-size the browser horizontally.  It will shrink no further than around 800 pixels, but it will expand as far as you drag the right edge of the browser.  It will also correctly overflow the table at the top and scroll it horizontally.

The thing I don't like about the first code snippet is where the scrollbar is.  I want it to show up within the borders of the fieldset, so even if I narrow the browser down to 800 pixels wide, I can see both the left and right sides of the fieldset's border.

The second code snippet is exactly the same as the first except I add another div tag to the mix, inside of the field set and around the grid. Notice how the top fieldset's width won't correctly shrink when you make the viewport of your browser narrower. Any ideas on why it doesn't work, what I can do to get it to work like the first code snippet?

I don't think I'm describing this clearly, but if you run the two side by side, and expand and contract the horizontal edge of your browser windows, you'll see the differences between the two.

I'm pretty new to CSS and HTML layout, so my understanding of why CSS handles sizing the way it does in some situations is still really confusing to me.

**Working HTML file:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css"></meta>

    <style type="text/css">
        #divBody {
            margin-top: 5px;
            top:24px;
            margin-top: 10px;
        }            
        #divContainer 
        {
            top: 5px;
            position:relative;
            min-height:100%;
            #width:expression(document.body.clientWidth < 830? "800": "90%" );
            width:90%;
            min-width: 800px;
            padding-bottom:70px;
        }
        #divMasterGrid {
            position:relative;
            margin:5px;
            top:5px;
            width:99%;
            margin:0 auto;
            overflow-x:scroll;
        }
        #divRadioButtonArea {
            position:relative;
            top:20px;
            height:51px;
            font-size: 12px;
            width:99%;
            margin:5px;
        }
    </style>
    <title>TEST TEST</title>
</head>


<body id="divBody">
    <div id="divContainer" class="gridRegion">

        <div id="divMasterGrid">
            <fieldset style="margin: 5px;">
                <legend style="font-size: 12px; color: #000;">Numbers</legend>
                <table border="1px">
                <tr>
                    <td>One
                    </td>
                    <td>Two
                    </td>
                    <td>Three
                    </td>
                    <td>Fout
                    </td>
                    <td>Five
                    </td>
                    <td>Six
                    </td>
                    <td>Seven
                    </td>
                    <td>Eight
                    </td>
                    <td>Nine
                    </td>
                    <td>Ten
                    </td>
                    <td>Eleven
                    </td>
                    <td>Twelve
                    </td>
                    <td>Thirteen
                    </td>
                    <td>Fourteen
                    </td>
                    <td>Fifteen
                    </td>
                    <td>Sixteen
                    </td>
                    <td>Seventeen
                    </td>
                    <td>Eighteen
                    </td>
                    <td>Nineteen
                    </td>
                    <td>Twenty
                    </td>                        
                </tr>
                </table>
            </fieldset>
        </div>


        <div id="divRadioButtonArea">
            <fieldset style=" padding-left: 5px;">
                <legend style="color: #000;  height:auto">Colors</legend>
                <table style="width:100%;padding-left:5%;padding-right:5%;">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type="radio" name="A" value="Y"/><label>Red</label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="radio" name="O" value="O"/><label>White</label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="radio" name="W"/><label>Blue</label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </fieldset>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Broken HTML file:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css"></meta>
    <style type="text/css">
        #divBody {
            margin-top: 5px;
            top:24px;
            margin-top: 10px;
        }            
        #divContainer 
        {
            top: 5px;
            position:relative;
            min-height:100%;
            #width:expression(document.body.clientWidth < 830? "800": "90%" );
            width:90%;
            min-width: 800px;
            padding-bottom:70px;
        }
        #divTopFieldSet {
            position:relative;
            margin:5px;
            top:5px;
            width:99%;
        }
        #divRadioButtonArea {
            position:relative;
            top:20px;
            height:51px;
            font-size: 12px;
            width:99%;
            margin:5px;
        }
        #divTable {
            position:relative;
            width:99%;
            margin:5px auto;
            overflow-x:scroll;
        }

    </style>
    <title>TEST TEST</title>
</head>


<body id="divBody">
    <div id="divContainer" class="gridRegion">

        <div id="divTopFieldSet">
            <fieldset style="margin: 5px;">
                <legend style="font-size: 12px; color: #000;">Numbers</legend>
                <div id="divTable">
                    <table border="1px">
                    <tr>
                        <td>One
                        </td>
                        <td>Two
                        </td>
                        <td>Three
                        </td>
                        <td>Fout
                        </td>
                        <td>Five
                        </td>
                        <td>Six
                        </td>
                        <td>Seven
                        </td>
                        <td>Eight
                        </td>
                        <td>Nine
                        </td>
                        <td>Ten
                        </td>
                        <td>Eleven
                        </td>
                        <td>Twelve
                        </td>
                        <td>Thirteen
                        </td>
                        <td>Fourteen
                        </td>
                        <td>Fifteen
                        </td>
                        <td>Sixteen
                        </td>
                        <td>Seventeen
                        </td>
                        <td>Eighteen
                        </td>
                        <td>Nineteen
                        </td>
                        <td>Twenty
                        </td>                        
                    </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </div>


        <div id="divRadioButtonArea">
            <fieldset style=" padding-left: 5px;">
                <legend style="color: #000;  height:auto">Colors</legend>
                <table style="width:100%;padding-left:5%;padding-right:5%;">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type="radio" name="A" value="Y"/><label>Red</label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="radio" name="O" value="O"/><label>White</label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="radio" name="W"/><label>Blue</label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </fieldset>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where I work, we have to support IE 7 (not 8), in addition to firefox, so I'm afraid we're stuck with the #width workaround.  Ie6 does not handle the min-width setting at all.  It's a shame.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you mean:

I've moved the overflow-x and width rules to `#divTopFieldSet` - the contents of the div correctly scrolls when the body becomes too narrow to contain the table.

To tell you the truth, I'm not 100% sure of the root cause of this. When an element with a percentage width is set to overflow:scroll, it doesn't automatically shrink to crop its contents - it seems like the children of the element play a part. Because the table has a minimum width of its own (determined by the contents of the cells), the surrounding container will not shrink past the outer edge of the table. On top of that, there is the calculation of percentage widths - `width:99%;` means '99% of the parent container's width' - if the parent container isn't based on the size of the viewport, that 99% won't change when you resize, either.

Applying the overflow rule to a container further up the tree (`divTopFieldSet`) does work, though.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css"></meta>
    <style type="text/css">
        #divBody {
            margin-top: 5px;
            top:24px;
            margin-top: 10px;
        }            
        #divContainer 
        {
            top: 5px;
            position:relative;
            min-height:100%;
            #width:expression(document.body.clientWidth < 830? "800": "90%" );
            width:90%;
            min-width: 800px;
            padding-bottom:70px;
        }
        #divTopFieldSet {
            position:relative;
            margin:5px;
            top:5px;
            width:99%;
            overflow-x:scroll;
        }
        #divRadioButtonArea {
            position:relative;
            top:20px;
            height:51px;
            font-size: 12px;
            width:99%;
            margin:5px;
        }
        #divTable {
            margin:5px auto;
        }

    </style>
    <title>TEST TEST</title>
</head>


<body id="divBody">
    <div id="divContainer" class="gridRegion">

        <div id="divTopFieldSet">
            <fieldset style="margin: 5px;">
                <legend style="font-size: 12px; color: #000;">Numbers</legend>
                <div id="divTable">
                    <table border="1px">
                    <tr>
                        <td>One
                        </td>
                        <td>Two
                        </td>
                        <td>Three
                        </td>
                        <td>Fout
                        </td>
                        <td>Five
                        </td>
                        <td>Six
                        </td>
                        <td>Seven
                        </td>
                        <td>Eight
                        </td>
                        <td>Nine
                        </td>
                        <td>Ten
                        </td>
                        <td>Eleven
                        </td>
                        <td>Twelve
                        </td>
                        <td>Thirteen
                        </td>
                        <td>Fourteen
                        </td>
                        <td>Fifteen
                        </td>
                        <td>Sixteen
                        </td>
                        <td>Seventeen
                        </td>
                        <td>Eighteen
                        </td>
                        <td>Nineteen
                        </td>
                        <td>Twenty
                        </td>                        
                    </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </div>


        <div id="divRadioButtonArea">
            <fieldset style=" padding-left: 5px;">
                <legend style="color: #000;  height:auto">Colors</legend>
                <table style="width:100%;padding-left:5%;padding-right:5%;">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type="radio" name="A" value="Y"/><label>Red</label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="radio" name="O" value="O"/><label>White</label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="radio" name="W"/><label>Blue</label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </fieldset>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Let us know if this isn't what you need...

Comment: Thanks for taking a look at it Beejamin.  I took a look at the first code snippet and ran it side by side with your solution, and it's about the same.

Based on what you said, it sounds like the order that the browser calculates width(s) has something to do with the fact that the second code snippet doesn't properly utilize the overflow scrolling mechanism.  Any ideas on the order that the browser calculates dimensions?

If the body is the parent div to everything and the container div took 90% of that width, and then it kept going down from parent-to-child, I would expect overflow to work.